# If I buy multiple 3 day xp buffs, will they stack?

Tags: league-of-legends

If I buy for example 6 x 3day bonus xp, will they stack giving me something like "Increase xp earned by 600%"?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if they stack, they stack in length, not in effectiveness. But I'm not completely sure, so don't take this as an answer.

Comment: @3ventic I don't know if I was clear enough but thanks for pointing this out. I was talking about effectiveness not time period. (English not my main language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you won't get a % bonus on your boost. If you buy a six 3 day boost at once you will just have a 100% boost for 18 days. So it would be better to just buy a 14 days boost + 3 days + 1 days if you really want the cheapest 18 days boost.

Usually it's better to buy per win boosts anyways except you want to play all day ;)

Edit: I just found out that you can stack Timed and per win IP boosts. So if you want a huge amount of IP in a short time you can do that for the most efficient way (If you aren't worried about spending more money of course)

Answer (score 0):

Buying multiple duration boosts only prolong the duration. Did it back when I started out, but haven't had any reasons to buy boosts within the last 2 years, so I can't guarantee that it's still that way. Nothing about booster changes has ever been mentioned though.